# javascript worker for more than one page element

Tags: javascript, shared-libraries

Lets say I have a javascript library (.js file) which does something like drawing an SVG graph on a div element that is on a page. The library applies business logic and also creates event handlers for when elements are clicked etc. Pseudo-code could look like this:

```
myLib = {};
myLib.dummy = null;
mylib.doStuff = function(divID) {
  //divID is the ID of the element on which SVG graph will be drawn
  //does graph drawing and sets up myLib.dummy for feedback or such, e.g.:
  myLib.dummy = $("#divID").width();
}
```

My question is: how do I handle a case where I want to apply this script to 2 (or more) elements on the same page, and then have seperate "instances" of myLib pertaining to each element. I know I cannot do call it like this from the page:

```
myLib.doStuff('topDiv');   //myLib.dummy will be say 400;
myLib.doStuff('bottomDiv');   //myLib.dummy will be say 600;
```

With the above code, I will no longer have access to myLib.dummy that pertains to div with ID = 'topDiv', since they are using the same namespace.

I suspect I am missing a design pattern or that the answer could be simply a case of namespacing.

I would appreciate any suggestions or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function makeALib() {
    var myLib = {};
    myLib.dummy = null;
    mylib.doStuff = function(divID) {
      //divID is the ID of the element on which SVG graph will be drawn
      //does graph drawing and sets up myLib.dummy for feedback or such, e.g.:
      myLib.dummy = $("#divID").width();
    }
    return myLib;
}

var libA = makeALib();
var libB = makeALib();

libA.doStuff('topDiv'); 
libB.doStuff('bottomDiv');
```

There's many different areas where you could introduct the seperation or indirection. Without knowing more about your usage context, its hard to say what's a good choice. But the above is one of many working choices.

Comment: Thanks rambo coder, that seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: For benefit of others, I think the answer means to say that libB.doStuff will/should typically have a different argument like libB.doStuff('bottomDiv');